# Group by with 3 joins

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm struggling with this query in where I want to get values from 3 tables

```
 SELECT  
  table1.cedtra as cedtra,
  table1.priape as priapetra,
  table1.segape as segapetra,
  table1.prinom as prinomtra,
  table1.segnom as segnomtra,
  table2.cedcon as cedcon,
  table2.ben as ben,
  table3.priape as priapeben,
  table3.segape as segapeben,
  table3.prinom as prinomben,
  table3.segnom as segnomben,
  table3.fecnac as fecnac,
  count(table1.cedtra) as numero 
  FROM table2, table1, table3 
  WHERE table2.id = table1.id 
  and table2.ben = table3.ben 
  and table2.doc = '12345' 
  and table2.codcit = '12345' 
  group by table1.cedtra, table2.ben, table1.cedtra, table1.priape, table1.segape, table1.prinom, table1.segnom, table3.priape, table3.segape, table3.prinom, table3.segnom, table3.fecnac 
  having count(table1.cedtra) > 3
```

I'm grouping by the fields that I select less the count as numero but this is throwing me this error:

> ORA-00979: is not a expression GROUP BY

I try with the aliases but I get the same result.

Any advice would be aprecciated!

Comment: You shouldn't use that join syntax anymore. It was made redundant more than twenty years ago for a reason. Use proper ANSI joins (`from table2 join table1 on ...`). Then it's queer to have two tables sharing their ID. If both tables use the same ID, why not put the data in only one table instead? At last it may be possible to get the query a bit straighter, but for this to know we would have to know more about the tables, their keys, their content.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - of course, it is possible that `id` is PK in one table and FK in the other. Nothing odd about that (if that's the case).

Comment: @mathguy: Only that you wouldn't call the ID of *another* table `id`, for this name suggests it's the ID of the table itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - you are not grouping by `table2.cedcon` but you `select` it.

Don't ever try to group by using column aliases in the SELECT clause - group by is processed before SELECT.

There is also no need to show the same column twice in GROUP BY.

Comment: What column is buing showed twice in Group by? Let me try

Comment: @JoseRojas:   The answer to your question is the FIRST sentence in my answer. The  column you have twice in GROUP BY is `table1.cedtra`, you don't need that, but that is NOT the cause of your error.

Comment: @JoseRojas - and, BobC makes a good point in his answer, too. That is not causes your error, but if you are counting `cedtra`, it doesn't make sense to group by it (let alone include it twice in GROUP BY) - and, of course, you shouldn't SELECT it either.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `table1.cedtra as cedtra` from your select list, and remove `table1.cedtra` from your group by